# saveSvgAsPng.js, getting 'Cannot set property 'prepareSvg' of undefined'

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, tomcat8

Hey hope you can help me with this.
I'm using saveSvgAsPng.js to get a PNG file from a SVG generated by NVD3.js 
when I run the project in local (grunt serve) is ok but when I run it on Tomcat I'm getting 'Cannot set property 'prepareSvg' of undefined'

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code required to reproduce the error?

Comment: I would like to do it but as I mentioned, when deploy the app in tomcat I'm just getting that error and searching the property in saveSvgAsPng.js found that prepareSvg is a function declared like this out$.prepareSvg = function(el, options, cb) {}

Comment: It looks like `out$` is undefined. Since it's an internal variable of saveSvgAsPng, there's probably some difference between your grunt and tomcat environments that is preventing saveSvgAsPng from functioning properly. That's all I can really say without a concrete example to work with.